# Why did Emily trap the Mayor?

Tags: character, preacher

In Preacher S01E09, Emily got the responsibility of feeding Cassidy in constant intervals and Tulip left enough animals to feed him.

But after witnessing Cassidy's condition, she tricked Miles Person (the mayor) into entering Cassidy's room and getting killed.

Emily seems like quite a nice lady throughout the season and even after knowing that God abandoned them all in S01E10 she still taught her kids a good lesson, even when the whole town was under mass hysteria.

So why did Emily trick the mayor into a death trap, even when she seems to be caring towards him all the time and even admitted that he is her boyfriend.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lucy Griffiths, who plays, Emily Woodward explains...

[**Inverse.com**](https://www.inverse.com/article/18921-lucy-griffiths-talks-preacher-season-1-finale)

> Because for her, the stakes are quite high. Getting rid of Miles was the difference between being free or not in her life, and not just for the moment. I’m sure that if she hadn’t killed him, she probably could have figured it out in a slightly less illegal way. But she, I think, feels strongly that if she doesn’t do this, she’ll be trapped forever. I guess that’s how depressed she’s feeling.

Plus Miles is a pretty creepy guy. He's covered up Quincannon's murders, he's still manipulative, creepy, and disrespectful of Emily. Whether he believes he "loves" her or not, he truly wanted to **own** her.

He gave her kids bad milk because she pissed him off...domestic abuse wasn't far behind probably.

He also threatens her faith in Jesse when he...

[**Wikia**](http://preacher.wikia.com/wiki/Miles_Person)

> ... explained sacrifices had to be made for the better of the community and the reality was that Jesse is a criminal and him being a preacher is a fantasy. Miles then told Emily she had to choose between fantasy or reality.

She chose Jesse and freed herself at the same time.

Comment: She was a wonderful character and is sorely missed in Season 2.  She balanced out Tulip's influence in Jesse's life but there were only so many original characters they could carry into the main series, I suppose